# Trying to Connect RaspberyPi4 to my monitor

Tags: pi-4, boot, hdmi, display

LG monitor LCD 22" max res: 1680x1050 60Hz(without overclock)

Using microHDMI to VGA

hostOS: w10 64bit guestOS: raspberypiOS 32bit

whenever adapter is connected to my monitor underscore(_) symbol appears in the top-left corner which flickers for 8-9 times and at the same time monitor starts beeping, in the end a window pops up saying: out of range 67.5 kHZ/ 60Hz

What I need to edit in /boot/config.txt file?

I would highly appreciate any feedback

Comment: Should work out of the box. What is the problem?

Comment: Depending on OS (which you haven't specified) config.txt settings are ignored. This is not a standard VGA resolution.

Comment: additional details have been provided ^

Comment: You still haven't specified OS - Buster & Bullseye use different video drivers. Try setting to standard VGA in config.txt

Comment: from raspberry pi imager I chose the recommended option: piOS 32bit, I assume it should be bullseye

Comment: P.S I can only access pi via ssh because of the issue